# Games with consecutive en passants

Tags: famous-games, en-passant

Games with consecutive en passants, that is one side makes two en passats captures in a row, are few and far between to my knowlegde. I only know of one example thanks to [Tim Krabbe](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/diary16txt.htm).

[Kudrin-R Douven, 1989](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1086879)

Can anyone find more games that have this unique feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched through all of the 1 317 676 games in [The Week in Chess](https://theweekinchess.com/twic) found two that fit the criteria.

1. [H Dang vs D H Nguyen, 2015](https://lichess.org/4cCk7Gi5)
2. [P Ponkratov vs V Fedoseev, 2016](https://lichess.org/NuxTdFcv)

Comment: Out of curiosity, which language was used and how long did the search take to run? Was it run on the PGN database directly or was the database pre-processed into another type of database?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a game with *three* consecutive en passants. The catch is that it's a proof game composition, rather than an over the board event. But it's spectacular because there is a completely unique sequence of moves ending with Black's 17th move to reach the diagram. This is the only known sound proof game for this task. Even reaching *one* en passant is not trivial in a proof game - a lot harder than forcing castling! There are no famous players here, but the composer is the well-known French ex-fighter pilot Thierry Le Gleuher.

I have not included the game yet because some might enjoy solving it.

```
[Title "Thierry Le Gleuher - R028c Probleemblad 01/1999 - 2. Preis ex aequo "]
[fen "6nr/p3b1p1/1k2bqp1/1p6/8/Kppp4/P4PPP/RNBQ1BNR w - - 0 1"]
```